# oracle merge update not support set a constant?

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
MERGE INTO XXD_BORROW_REPAYMENT BR
USING XXD_BORROW B ON (B.BORROWID=BR.BORROWID AND B.type!=13)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET BR.TOTALTERM=B.TIMELIMIT


MERGE INTO XXD_BORROW_REPAYMENT BR
USING XXD_BORROW B ON (B.BORROWID=BR.BORROWID AND B.type==13)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET BR.TOTALTERM=1
```

why the first sql is right,the second sql is wrong, oracle merge not support set a constant?

Comment: Perhaps Oracle doesn't support `==`.  Only one equals sign is used for comparisons.

Comment: You should also post the error. I have a feeling that this is to blame: B.type==13 --> use only one equal sign character ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your statement "B.type==13" , it seems you wanted to implement a comparison of B.type with "13". Unfortunately oracle plsql doesnot support "==". You need to use a single "=" for any comparison. Look below the proof of concept for the same.

```
declare
var varchar(10):= '13';
begin

  if var == '13' then
   dbms_output.put_line('Hi');
 end if; 

end;
```

This simple block ends up thorwing an error: "Encountered the symbol "-" when expecting..."